# Creating Indexes with mapping in ES 6.5 on Java REST Client [6.5] API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am new to elastic search and trying to integrate an autocomplete feature for an app by following the article https://www.elastic.co/blog/you-complete-me.

I have followed the below approach to do the same.

Event class

```
       public class Event {

        private Long eventId;
        private Long catalogId;
        private Long orgId;
        private String orgName;
        private String catalogName;
        private String name;
        private String eventStatus;
.....
    }
```

An objectmapper is used to convert the event object to json string. Here is the code to insert the document

```
public String createEventDocument(Event document) throws Exception {
    IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(INDEX, TYPE, document.idAsString())
            .source(convertEventDocumentToMap(document));
    //create mapping with a complete field
    IndexResponse indexResponse = client.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    return indexResponse.getResult().name();
}
```

Convert code

```
private Map<String, Object> convertEventDocumentToMap(Event evt) {
    return objectMapper.convertValue(evt, Map.class);
}
```

I would like to create an index, and setup the completion suggester for the name_suggest field. How can I achieve the same ?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: So that mean you have a filed `name_suggest ` in your `Event` right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution to do the same. Create index with mappers first and insert the data

```
 public String createEventDocument(Event document) throws Exception {
    GetIndexRequest request = new GetIndexRequest();
    request.indices(INDEX);
    boolean exists = client.indices().exists(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    if(!exists){
        createIndexWithMapping();
    }
    IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(INDEX, TYPE, document.idAsString())
            .source(convertEventDocumentToMap(document));
    //create mapping with a complete field
    IndexResponse indexResponse = client.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    return indexResponse.getResult().name();
}

private boolean createIndexWithMapping() throws IOException {
            CreateIndexRequest createIndexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(INDEX);
    XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
    builder.startObject();
    {
        builder.startObject( "properties" );
        {
            builder.startObject( "name_suggest" );
            {
                builder.field( "type", "completion" );
            }
            builder.endObject();
        }
        builder.endObject();
    }
    builder.endObject();
    createIndexRequest.mapping(TYPE,builder);
    createIndexRequest.timeout(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(2));
    CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = client.indices().create(createIndexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    return createIndexResponse.isAcknowledged();

}
```

Comment: what is the class for ***TYPE*** in 

createIndexRequest.mapping(TYPE,builder)

Answer (score 1):

You can do some thing like,

```
public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
                RestClient.builder(
                        new HttpHost( "192.168.1.245", 9200, "http" ) ) );
        try
        {
            createIndex( client );
            updateIndexMapping( client );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void createIndex( RestHighLevelClient client ) throws IOException
    {

        //1. create index
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put( "eventId", "eventId" );
        map.put( "catalogId", "catalogId" );
        map.put( "orgId", "orgId" );
        map.put( "orgName", "orgName" );
        map.put( "catalogName", "catalogName" );
        map.put( "name", "name" );
        map.put( "eventStatus", "eventStatus" );

        IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest( "event", "event", "123" )
                .source( map );

        IndexResponse indexResponse = client.index( indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT );
        indexResponse.getResult().name();
    }

    private static void updateIndexMapping( RestHighLevelClient client ) throws IOException
    {
        //2. update index mapping to set the filed 'name_suggest' into type 'completion'
        PutMappingRequest request = new PutMappingRequest( "event" );
        request.type( "event" );

        XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
        builder.startObject();
        {
            builder.startObject( "properties" );
            {
                builder.startObject( "name_suggest" );
                {
                    builder.field( "type", "completion" );
                }
                builder.endObject();
            }
            builder.endObject();
        }
        builder.endObject();
        request.source( builder );
        request.timeout( TimeValue.timeValueMinutes( 1 ) );

        AcknowledgedResponse acknowledgedResponse = client.indices().putMapping( request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT );

        //check if the request is sucess
        boolean acknowledged = acknowledgedResponse.isAcknowledged();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I will check and update. Is updateIndexMapping is a one time activity or do we need to do the same for all the insert ?

Comment: I have tried similar to this one yesterday         XContentBuilder mappingBuilder = jsonBuilder().startObject().
                startObject("your_type_name").startObject("properties").
                startObject("your_completion_field").
                field("type", "completion").endObject()
                .endObject().endObject().endObject();

        PutMappingRequest request = new PutMappingRequest(INDEX);
        request.source(mappingBuilder);

Comment: Great!. `updateIndexMapping` is a one time activity it just updates the `mapping` filed of the index. Yeh there are several ways to achieve what you need. I think it is better if you create your `index`, `index mapping`, and `index settings` according to your requirement and then index/insert data. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-create-index.html

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have followed your suggestions but the code is not working as expected. Full code and errors are available at https://gist.github.com/shyjuzz/4a1820a74cbfd214f7a1c7a3bf670828

Kindly check the same

Comment: `[type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=mapper [name_suggest] of different type, current_type [text], merged_type [completion]` this is because you have already created the field `name_suggest` with type `text`.

Comment: Yea, while inserting the data with json, it automatically creates a text field for the same. Any idea to fix the same ? to insert the complete field as well ?

Comment: I have created the index with mapping before the insert operation and seems to be working..Will update soon

Comment: great! that would be the better way. and there is a way to restrict the index not to change when adding data. you might need that also

Comment: Thank you @Dush. do you have any idea to add the input and output fields ? "name_suggest" : { 
    "input" :      [ 
      "Mercure Hotel Munich", 
      "Mercure Munich" 
    ],
    "output":      "Hotel Mercure"
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187476/discussion-between-shyju-m-and-dush).