# Completion Suggester in Elasticsearch 6.5.4 with Java REST Client API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search and trying to integrate the [completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) to one of my application by following the article [You Complete Me](https://www.elastic.co/blog/you-complete-me)

I have inserted the sample [data](https://gist.github.com/shyjuzz/d48973758e9ec80d6857690824b22591) to the ES with mapping and the below CURL query(windows) returns the [result](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/shyjuzz/d48973758e9ec80d6857690824b22591/raw/433be24a966b53c704bb80709dd1b06befe4f465/res.json)

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:9200/hotels/_search?pretty -d^
"{^
    \"suggest\": {^
        \"hotel_suggest\" : {^
            \"prefix\" : \"hot\", ^
            \"completion\" : { ^
                \"field\" : \"name_suggest\" ^
            }^
        }^
    }^
}"
```

Unfortunalty the below code using the Java API is not returning any documents from the DB (Just printing the results for the testing purpose)

```
    public String suggestSearch() throws IOException {
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("hotels");
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
//        searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());

        SuggestionBuilder termSuggestionBuilder =
                SuggestBuilders.termSuggestion("name").text("hot");
        SuggestBuilder suggestBuilder = new SuggestBuilder();
        suggestBuilder.addSuggestion("name_suggest", termSuggestionBuilder);
        searchSourceBuilder.suggest(suggestBuilder);

        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);


        Suggest suggest = searchResponse.getSuggest();
        TermSuggestion termSuggestion = suggest.getSuggestion("name_suggest");

        for (TermSuggestion.Entry entry : termSuggestion.getEntries()) {
            for (TermSuggestion.Entry.Option option : entry) {
                String suggestText = option.getText().string();
                System.out.println(suggestText);
            }
        }
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
```

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: Have you look at logs in elasticsearch cluter to see if there are any exceptions?

Comment: @Dush The query result seems to be empty and no exceptions found  in the console and able to get the results for search query as well. Shall I check any specific logs ?

Comment: yes it might help you if you could look at the logs when your request hit the cluster normally you can find the log(s) in `.../elasticsearch-6.2.2/logs/cluster.log'.

Comment: @Dush I have checked the logs as you said and couldn't find any exceptions

Comment: According to es doc, If you want to use `Completion Suggeste` you have to change your code `SuggestBuilders.completionSuggestion( "name" ).prefix( "hot" );` and `CompletionSuggestion entries=suggest.getSuggestion( "name_suggest" );`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here a sample code to get results from the example  [completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html)

```
public static void suggestSearch() 
    {

        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
                RestClient.builder(
                        new HttpHost( "your-ip-here", 9200, "http" ) ) );

        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest( "music" );
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

        SuggestionBuilder termSuggestionBuilder = SuggestBuilders.completionSuggestion( "suggest" ).prefix( "nev" );
        SuggestBuilder suggestBuilder = new SuggestBuilder();
        suggestBuilder.addSuggestion( "song-suggest", termSuggestionBuilder );
        searchSourceBuilder.suggest( suggestBuilder );

        searchRequest.source( searchSourceBuilder );
        SearchResponse searchResponse = null;

        try
        {
            searchResponse = client.search( searchRequest );
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Suggest suggest = searchResponse.getSuggest();
        CompletionSuggestion entries = suggest.getSuggestion( "song-suggest" );

        for ( CompletionSuggestion.Entry entry : entries )
        {
            for ( CompletionSuggestion.Entry.Option option : entry.getOptions() )
            {
                String suggestText = option.getText().string();
                System.out.println( suggestText );
            }
        }
    }
```

And for the example [you-complete-me](https://www.elastic.co/blog/you-complete-me)

```
public static void suggestSearch()
    {

        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
                RestClient.builder(
                        new HttpHost( "192.168.1.245", 9200, "http" ) ) );

        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest( "hotels" );
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
       searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());

        CompletionSuggestionBuilder completionSuggestionBuilder = SuggestBuilders.completionSuggestion( "name_suggest" ).prefix( "M" );

        SuggestBuilder suggestBuilder = new SuggestBuilder();
        suggestBuilder.addSuggestion( "name_suggest", completionSuggestionBuilder );
        searchSourceBuilder.suggest( suggestBuilder );

        searchRequest.source( searchSourceBuilder );
        SearchResponse searchResponse = null;

        try
        {
            searchResponse = client.search( searchRequest );
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Suggest suggest = searchResponse.getSuggest();
        CompletionSuggestion entries = suggest.getSuggestion( "name_suggest" );

        for ( CompletionSuggestion.Entry entry : entries )
        {
            for ( CompletionSuggestion.Entry.Option option : entry.getOptions() )
            {
                String suggestText = option.getText().string();
                System.out.println( suggestText );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Dush.. It is working but the query returns the duplicate records also.

Comment: Could you please have a look at this questions as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54360057/creating-indexes-with-mapping-in-es-6-5-on-java-rest-client-6-5-api

Comment: There is option like `completionSuggestion( "name_suggest" ).prefix( "M" ).skipDuplicates( true );` to avoid duplicates

Comment: sure, ill have a look.